# File Not Found Exception when Referencing server HTML File

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, xml-parsing, doctype

`<?xml version="1.0"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "file:///aaa/bbb/vvv/sss/dtd/htmlentities.dtd">`

The above code is from the html file on the UNIX server. My application uses this html file by parsing it. Now I'm running my application by creating a local work space and I need to bring down all the html files from my server. The html file has the reference that the DTD is located at some directory. When I tried to run the application it gave me a "FileNotFoundException" so I copied it from my server to my local environment. How can I give a reference to that DTD file?

Comment: This question misses at least: 1) A descriptive title 2) A mention of the programming language involved 3) Code 4) A clear question

Answer (score 0):

Just change the path for "file:///" to point to the local copy of the dtd.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the relative path of DTD file, else try with absolute path.